# Do I need to perform a full format on a newly purchased USB thumb drive?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I wonder if I need to do a full format a newly purchased USB thumb drive or not? I mean the thumb drive is already formatted and all.

Thanks.

Comment: Format it to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @JakeGould . It was already formatted as exFat which suits my needs. The storage capacity is 128GB, so exFat would be most suited. The reason I am asking if a full format is needed is because I want to know if this would affect the normal operation of the drive, if I skipped this step seeing it was already exFat.

Comment: Not required but recommended for brand new flash drive is to check if it really can store the amount of data it claims (or if it is a fake, e.g. a stick with 4GB flash that claims to have 128GB). You can use `h2testw` or similar tools:  https://www.raymond.cc/blog/test-and-detect-fake-or-counterfeit-usb-flash-drives-bought-from-ebay-with-h2testw/

Comment: Factory format is more reliable than yours. If it works, leave it as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the information, harrymc. @Robert Thank you for the great tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're happy with the default there's no need to change it.

Default would usually be [MBR/FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) of some description, which is sufficient for most purposes, including cross-platform usage.

Comment: Thanks for the infomation.